# PhD opportunity | Confusion

Tags: phd, thesis, academic-life, supervision, thesis-committee

Recently I am offered a Ph.D. position ( Industry Project) in Australia and they want me to join ASAP. (It will be fully funded , fees will be waived off and even I will get monthly stipend)

but my question and confusion is that currently, I am doing Master by Research (2nd year in Australia) and should be ending it by the end of 2019 (or even a bit earlier If I can complete and submit my thesis but It will take at least 3-4 months). My Master research is also fully funded. (fees is waived off and getting a monthly scholarship)

I am confused and do not know what to do? Either complete my Master(but I may lose this Ph.D. opportunity) or leave Master and start a new Ph.D. or some other option?

Note: Research Areas are totally different in both cases.

Please advise??

updating:

i) The future plan was to do a PhD and join Academia
ii) Joined Master by Research instead of Ph.D. earlier to fill the gap which I feel is filled now after working for 10years in an Industry.
iii) The current area is hot but I feel my programming skills are not up to that level. for Ph.D. I know I will need programming skills but I feel I can manage that

Comment: There is no right answer. Try to negotiate a later start date and ask for advice from the PhD supervisor.

Comment: "ASAP" means "as soon as possible". In your case, "possible" will be when you have finished your Master's. You need to ask them for a later start date.

Comment: @astronat for PhD they said Master is not the requirement

Comment: Guys  I have updated my question